# My python datetime is not getting verified in my django application

Tags: python, django, datetime, web

I am trying to create a delete button in django app which sends the date whose entry has to be deleted to views.py when i click that button. Then I convert the date to correct format and try to fetch and delete the object from models.py whose date matches the date which is recieved from the delete button. The problem is that the date from delete button and date of objects stored in database isn't matching due to some reason. So the object isn't getting deleted. I am receiving this error when i click the delete button:

> Entry matching query does not exist.

my views.py for handling the delete button:

```
date = request.POST.get('date')#returns a date like Aug. 5, 2020, 12:58 a.m.
date = date.replace('.', '')#here i replace the . from date otherwise it gives errors
date = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')#converting the date to required format
print(date)#prints: 2020-08-05 00:58:00
print(type(date))# prints: <class 'datetime.datetime'>
req_entry = Entry.objects.filter(date=date).get()
req_entry.delete()
```

I tried to find in which format the date is stored through shell

```
entry = Entry.objects.all().first()
print(entry.date)#prints: datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 0, 58, 50, 216525, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I know that the date format in which data is stored and my date format aren't matching..How can i make sure that they match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date) field lookup.

For example:

```
req_entry = Entry.objects.filter(date__date=date).get()
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro...I can't tell u how grateful i am to you...i was trying to solve that problem from the past 3 hours...can u please explain why your solution worked?

Comment: Cool. Just checking - did you want to filter by date or by datetime specifically? The `date` field lookup strips off the time from the date and just compares the dates.

Comment: I noticed that the example `Entry` that you posted had different seconds and milliseconds than the datetime you tried to filter with.

Comment: @D Malan actually i faced that exact problem..when i created two entries with the same date then it returned two separate objects as it just verified the date..how do i make sure that date and time both gets matched..